# While i am doing undo bitmap alpha value is changing in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

In my application am using canvas and adding image to canvas as bitmap.I am making bitmap transparent and erasing bitmap.I need to undo erased bitmap while trying sometimes the bitmap which is transparent it is becoming more brightness i think its alpha value is changing.How to avoid this please help me how to solve this issue.Below is my code.

```
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          int num=imgbit.size();

          if(num>=1)
           {
              unoo=1;
               if(num==1)
               {

                 bitmap=null;
                 bitmap=imgbit.get(0);
                   Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setAlpha(178);
                   pcanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0,0, paint);
                 undo.setEnabled(false);  

               }

                if((num!=1))
               {

                   bitmap=null;
                   if(capture==true)
                   {
                  bitmap=imgbit.get(num-2);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       bitmap=imgbit.get(num-1);
                   }
                   Paint paint = new Paint();
                   paint.setAlpha(178);
                    pcanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,paint);

               }

               imgbit.remove(num-1);


           }
        capture=false;
```